# How to hide and show table in C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to hide and show table,
but it's working.

Code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
           //Here I hide the table 
            tableCarDetails.Style.Add("display","none");
        }
    }
```

In the below code if I give value as II-61 in textbox I want to show that table,
but the below code is not working:

```
   protected void txtGrade_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtGrade.Text == "II-61")
        {  
            if (tableCarDetails.Style["display"] == "none")
            {
                tableCarDetails.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `tableCarDetails` is your table? Does it have `runat=server` set?

Comment: Yes tableCarDetails is table ID it have runat=server

Comment: have you debugged the code? where exatly its creating problem?

Comment: Set `tableCarDetails.Style["display"] = "block"` instead of changing `visible`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cant you try this?

```
protected void txtGrade_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtGrade.Text == "II-61")
        {  
            if(tableCarDetails.css("display") == "none")
            {
                  tableCarDetails.Style.Add("display","block");
            }
         }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this not mixing up C# and jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged `jQuery`

Use [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

ie.

```
$( ".txtboxClass" ).change(function() {
    var value=  this.val();
    if(value == "II-61")
    {
        $(".tableClass" ).toggle();
    }
});
```

Haven't tested this bit of code, but should work!

Answer (score 0):

tableCarDetails.Visible does not affect display... it determines whether the table is rendered as Html or not. Either set tableCarDetails.Style["display"] = "block" or better yet use tableCarDetails.Visible = false in your Page_Load event.